I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. I am unablr to access Toshiba flash drives though other brands work. This is the error message: "error mounting/
I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.  It will not mount Toshiba flash drives:  other brands work fine.  This is the error message:  error mounting/ev/sdb1 at/media/ann/TOSHIBA EXT1:wrong fs type, bad superblock on/dev/sdb1, missing codepage or /helper program.  How do I fox this?

Your error message implies you have a file-system problem, but as you've provided minimal details we can't be more specific. Your toshiba brand devices were possibly uncleanly mounted, need file-system checks (using appropriate command(s) for your unstated fs) or other. You don't specify how many devices (1, 10, 100, 1000?) except its plural/many, but I'd explore file-system details & check for issues there first; cleanly unmount/eject in future etc.

Please edit the question to clarify how many Toshiba flash drives you have tried. Also, test the drive(s) in a different machine (any OS) to see if they mount.
